# How to validate a terraform defined security group?

Tags: github, amazon-ec2, terraform

Is there any way to validate that a proposed new security group is syntactically correct for terraform and aws? What happens is that I am asked to review security group adds and changes but I spend not much time working with terraform. I've learned the basics of what to see in main.tf output.tf and variable.tf for these sg modules. Once I approve the module change in github it gets committed and merged to the rest of the vpc repository. At some point a terrform plan will be run and that would show any errors. But what I'm wondering is if there's a program that would validate that the proposed security group code in main/variables are syntactically correct before I approve it.

Comment: may be this will help: terraform validate

Answer (score 0):

`terraform validate` does what you need.

> The terraform validate command is used to validate the syntax of the
>   terraform files. Terraform performs a syntax check on all the
>   terraform files in the directory, and will display an error if any of
>   the files doesn't validate.

From the official [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/validate.html).

An example validating the `src` directory:

```
terraform validate src
```

An example validating the `src` directory specifying a variable `foo`:

```
terraform validate -var 'foo=bar' src
```

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. That's a big help as I only look at terraform sporadically. I'm mostly looking to see that the SG rule makes sense but it's assuring to know that that its syntax is correct.